# @OneToMany - how to skip flagged child elements?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

2 entities that I have: `Country` and `User`

```
@Entity(name = "Country")
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private boolean removed;
}
```

Entity `User` has an attribute, `removed`type `boolean` and we need to skip/ignore all `User`'s that have `removed` equals `true`.

Does Hibernate provide any suitable mechanism to achieving my goal?

**P.S:** Google says that potentially I can use annotations like: `@JoinColumn`, `@JoinColumnOrFormula`, but based on docs that I have read, annotations mentioned above belong to `@ManyToOne` scenario, in my particular case I have `@OneToMany` relation.

Comment: Could you please clarify what or when exactly you want to skip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With hibernate, using `@Where` on the entity should do the trick. This will prevent any user to be loaded which has the removed flag set to `true`. You might find more information in the [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where)

If you only want this to be on the collection, you can add the annotation on the relationship

```
@Entity(name = "Country")
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @Where( clause = "removed = false" ) // <- here
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to load any removed user at all, the annotation can be added to the class.

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
@Where( clause = "removed = false" ) // <- here
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private boolean removed;
}
```

A word of caution, I haven't used this, but I assume that if you have other entities with linked to a user which has the flag set to true, you'll need to update the annotations to allow nulls.

For example, imagine an ecomerce site, an Order is linked to a user. Loading an Order linked to a removed user will fail, or you can ammend the annotations so it returns an order with a `null` user. I hope this makes sense!